# How can I tell if my OpenShift application has been deleted?

Tags: openshift

I created an `OpenShift` account and installed `CommaFeed`.

It was working for a few weeks and then suddenly disappeared.

I can log in to my account,  I can click on the URL to the application but I don't get a response (blank page in firefox and 'Oops! This link appears to be broken.' in chrome).

I found the admin page and clicked on the reload symbol.  I got a message that the application had been restarted.  But the behavior is not changed.

Is there an error log I can look at?

Comment: Once you login to OpenShift, click on My Applications.  You should see the name of your application with a > symbol next to it.  Click on the > symbol.

Comment: The next page has a link titled "Want to log in to your application?".  Click on that.

Comment: The next page will show you that address/login to use to connect via ssh.  I used putty to connect.  I found the instructions at https://www.openshift.com/page/install-and-setup-putty-ssh-client-for-windows

Comment: Now that I'm logged in, I see using find * | grep log$ that there are files I can look at.  I still don't know what is wrong, but at least now I can poke around.

Comment: Based on the error logs, it looks like the application is not connecting to the mySQL database.  Now I am left wondering how to restart that.  I don't see any links and the webpages note that it is "shared".

Comment: A few things to check while you're logged in:
mysql logs:  ~/mysql/log/.  
whether you can connect:  type 'mysql'
diskspace:  'quota -s'

Answer (score 0):

Going off your comments, You were able to locate your application but now you are unable to get mysql up and running.

First check to make sure `mysql` is up and running.

`rhc ssh <yourappname>`
`ps aux | grep mysql`

If `mysql` is running then next you'll want to doublecheck your code to make sure you're using the right environment variables to connect to your application.